I had been/was working late because my boss had assigned
Sarah and John live together. Sarah leaves her car parked at work and takes a taxi home. After she has arrived home, John returns from work. He first checks the garage and then finds Sarah in the kitchen where she's having a late supper. He says to her: "Sarah, I didn't see your car in the garage." She replies to him with the following:
1. Oh, it's parked at the office. I'd been working late because my boss had assigned me some extra tasks, so I felt pretty tired and decided to take a taxi home instead of driving.
2. Oh, it's parked at the office. I was working late because my boss had assigned me some extra tasks, so I felt pretty tired and decided to take a taxi home instead of driving.
Version #1 with "had been working" means that Sarah made the decision to take a taxi home after finishing work. That is, the reference point for the past perfect continuous "had been working" is the end of the work day.
Version #2 with "was working" means that she made that decision while still working.
In both #1 and #2, the bolded "had" before the word "assigned" is optional, and either way, it's clear that Sarah started working on the extra tasks after her boss assigned them to her. Are both versions correct in the context given, and is my analysis of the bolded tenses correct? Thanks.

We have tons of answers about this.   I'd been working late because my boss assigned me, not had assigned me. The past prefect is preceded by a  past tense, express or implied, not another past perfect, usually.  If you want to use was working and had assigned, that works too.

Both versions seem natural enough to me.

Would was working and assigned works too? OR are we obliged to use past perfect for assign to make the reader understand that it happened before John did not see the car( even if it is written because which should be enough to make the reader understand what comes first )

@YvesLefol No, the pp is not obligatory. It depends on what you want to say; Do you or do you not want to show that something preceded it?
